# Ways to send emails with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail

I am trying to write a python program that could send emails automatically (through ...@gmail.com). But I keep getting the following error message:

```
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
```

I did some research on this and now it appears that google no longer allows third party apps to login for security reasons.

[image: photo of google]

This made me wonder if there were any other methods to get this in order?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I now (since June 2022) send an email via Gmail using a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026671/how-do-i-now-since-june-2022-send-an-email-via-gmail-using-a-python-script)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send email from python with 2 Factor Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63803904/how-can-i-send-email-from-python-with-2-factor-authentication)